# Iterate over rows polars rust

Tags: dataframe, rust, rust-polars

I am trying to iterate over each row of a Polars rust dataframe.

In this endeavour, I have found `df.get` but the documentation says that this is slow. Then I have tried `df.column("col").get` but this seems to pose similar problems.

What is the correct way to process each row of the dataframe? I need to upload it to a database and turn it into structs.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a fast way to iterate rows without first transposing the dataframe; dataframes are columnar structures, so pulling all of the data together for a row means a lookup per column.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you activate the `rows` feature in polars, you can try:

`DataFrame::get_row` and `DataFrame::get_row_amortized`.

The latter is preferred, as that reduces heap allocations by reusing the row buffer.

### Anti-pattern

This will be slow. Asking for rows from a columnar data storage will incur many cache misses and goes trough several layers of indirection.

### Slightly better

What would be slightly better is using rust iterators. This will have less indirection than the `get_row` methods.

```rust
df.as_single_chunk_par();
let mut iters = df.columns(["foo", "bar", "ham"])?
    .iter().map(|s| s.iter()).collect::<Vec<_>>();

for row in 0..df.height() {
    for iter in &mut iters {
        let value = iter.next().expect("should have as many iterations as rows");
        // process value
    }
}
```

If your `DataFrame` consists of a single data type, you should downcast the `Series` to a `ChunkedArray`, this will speed up iteration.

In the snippet below, we'll assume the data type is `Float64`.

```rust
let mut iters = df.columns(["foo", "bar", "ham"])?
    .iter().map(|s| Ok(s.f64()?.into_iter())).collect::<Result<Vec<_>>>()?;

for row in 0..df.height() {
    for iter in &mut iters {
        let value = iter.next().expect("should have as many iterations as rows");
        // process value
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good to know, but how does one access items in the row by key? This just iterates through them all, and you have no way to know which column you're in without keeping track of it yourself by column index.