# How do I serialize Polars DataFrame Row/HashMap of `AnyValue` into JSON?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I have a row of a polars dataframe created using iterators reading a parquet file from this method: [Iterate over rows polars rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72440403/iterate-over-rows-polars-rust)

I have constructed a HashMap that represents an individual row and I would like to now convert that row into JSON.

This is what my code looks like so far:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::iter::zip;
use std::{fs::File, collections::HashMap};

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {

    let file = File::open("0.parquet").unwrap();
    let mut df = ParquetReader::new(file).finish()?;
    dbg!(df.schema());
    let fields = df.fields();
    let columns: Vec<&String> = fields.iter().map(|x| x.name()).collect();

    df.as_single_chunk_par();
    let mut iters = df.iter().map(|s| s.iter()).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    for _ in 0..df.height() {
        let mut row = HashMap::new();
        for (column, iter) in zip(&columns, &mut iters) {
            let value = iter.next().expect("should have as many iterations as rows");
            row.insert(column, value);
        }
        dbg!(&row);
        let json = serde_json::to_string(&row).unwrap();
        dbg!(json);
        break;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

And I have the following feature flags enabled: `["parquet", "serde", "dtype-u8", "dtype-i8", "dtype-date", "dtype-datetime"]`.

I am running into the following error at the `serde_json::to_string(&row).unwrap()` line:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("the enum variant AnyValue::Datetime cannot be serialized", line: 0, column: 0)', src/main.rs:47:48
```

I am also unable to implement my own serialized for AnyValue::DateTime because of `only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for types defined outside of the crate`.

What's the best way to serialize this row into JSON?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this error by using a match statement over value to change it from a Datetime to an Int64.

```rust
let value = match value {
                AnyValue::Datetime(value, TimeUnit::Milliseconds, _) => AnyValue::Int64(value),
                x => x
            };
row.insert(column, value);
```

Root cause is there is no enum variant for Datetime in the impl Serialize block: https://docs.rs/polars-core/0.24.0/src/polars_core/datatypes/mod.rs.html#298

Although this code now works, it outputs data that looks like:

```py
{'myintcolumn': {'Int64': 22342342343},
 'mylistoclumn': {'List': {'datatype': 'Int32', 'name': '', 'values': []}},
 'mystrcolumn': {'Utf8': 'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum'}
```

So you likely to be customizing the serialization here regardless of the data type.

Update: If you want to get the JSON without all of the inner nesting, I had to do a gnarly match statement:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::iter::zip;
use std::{fs::File, collections::HashMap};
use serde_json::json;

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {

    let file = File::open("0.parquet").unwrap();
    let mut df = ParquetReader::new(file).finish()?;
    dbg!(df.schema());
    let fields = df.fields();
    let columns: Vec<&String> = fields.iter().map(|x| x.name()).collect();

    df.as_single_chunk_par();
    let mut iters = df.iter().map(|s| s.iter()).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    for _ in 0..df.height() {
        let mut row = HashMap::new();
        for (column, iter) in zip(&columns, &mut iters) {
            let value = iter.next().expect("should have as many iterations as rows");
            let value = match value {
                AnyValue::Null => json!(Option::<String>::None),
                AnyValue::Int64(val) => json!(val),
                AnyValue::Int32(val) => json!(val),
                AnyValue::Int8(val) => json!(val),
                AnyValue::Float32(val) => json!(val),
                AnyValue::Float64(val) => json!(val),
                AnyValue::Utf8(val) => json!(val),
                AnyValue::List(val) => {
                    match val.dtype() {
                        DataType::Int32 => ({let vec: Vec<Option<_>> = val.i32().unwrap().into_iter().collect(); json!(vec)}),
                        DataType::Float32 => ({let vec: Vec<Option<_>> = val.f32().unwrap().into_iter().collect(); json!(vec)}),
                        DataType::Utf8 => ({let vec: Vec<Option<_>> = val.utf8().unwrap().into_iter().collect(); json!(vec)}),
                        DataType::UInt8 => ({let vec: Vec<Option<_>> = val.u8().unwrap().into_iter().collect(); json!(vec)}),
                        x => panic!("unable to parse list column: {} with value: {} and type: {:?}", column, x, x.inner_dtype())
                    }
                },
                AnyValue::Datetime(val, TimeUnit::Milliseconds, _) => json!(val),
                x => panic!("unable to parse column: {} with value: {}", column, x)
            };
            row.insert(*column as &str, value);
        }
        let json = serde_json::to_string(&row).unwrap();
        dbg!(json);
        break;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```