# I just want to plot using Plotters data from a Polars dataframe in rust

Tags: plot, rust, rust-polars

I just want to plot data from a Polars datafram into a plotters image. I need help. I followed [Iterate over rows polars rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72440403/iterate-over-rows-polars-rust) to have this :

```
let  iters = dataset
     .columns(["x", "y"])?
     .iter()
     .map(|s| Ok(s.f64()?.into_iter()))
     .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, Box<dyn Error>>>()?;
```

and I want to do something like

```
chart
        .draw_series(
            x.zip(y)map(|(x, y)| Circle::new((x, x), 3, BLUE.filled())),
        )?
        .label("data")
        .legend(|(x, y)| Circle::new((x, y), 3, BLUE.filled()));
```

But it doesnt work. I need help. Maybe I am missing something,but I  think it should be easy to use the biggest dataframe library with the biggest plotting library.

All I could make work is using one column with

```
let  mut iters = dataset.groundtruth
        .columns(["x", "y"])?
        .iter()
        .map(|s| Ok(s.f64()?.into_iter()))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, Box<dyn Error>>>()?;

let x = &mut  iters[0];

chart
        .draw_series(
            // x.filter(|x| x.is_some())
            x.map(|(x)| Circle::new((x.unwrap(), x.unwrap()), 3, BLUE.filled())),
        )?
        .label("data")
        .legend(|(x, y)| Circle::new((x, y), 3, BLUE.filled()));
```

I really like rust, but using dataframes and plotting library is a pain. Maybe it is a lifetime issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use into_no_null_iter() to get dataset.column("x")?.f64()?.into_no_null_iter().collect();